# updating a record at runtime using jdbc

Tags: jdbc, runtime

I have problem updating my password at runtime.
It gives no error but it just doesn't work.
Please help .
Thanks in Advance!

Here is my code:

//HERE IS THE PROBLEM PART WHICH IS NOT WORKING

```
try {
    System.out.println("id is : "+j);
    System.out.println("What do you want your new password to be?");
    Scanner s8=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s7=s8.nextLine();
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection  con5=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login","root","q");
    PreparedStatement ps=con5.prepareStatement("update pass set password=?     where id=?");
    ps.setString(1,s7);
    ps.setInt(2,j);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: There is no error but this part shows no effect on my table

Answer (score 0):

You miss the execution of your statement using [PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()).
From javadoc

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which
>   must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as
>   INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing,
>   such as a DDL statement.